# DocuSign sign via fax option

Tags: docusignapi

I have created an Envelope using DocuSign SOAP API call.
I included myself as a remote recipient and have selected an option of signing document on paper and have also selected an option of sending signed document back using fax.
I have faxed the signed document back to DocuSign along with cover sheet as instructed but my envelope status have not been updates as "Completed".

- Approximately, how long does it take for DocuSign to update the status of the recipient/envelope if a recipient sends signed document using fax?
- If there are required tags/fields on the document that the recipient needs to fill out in order to complete signing process and he/she does not fill out those tags while signing on paper, what does DocuSign do? How does DocuSign send out a message to the recipient that he/she needs to fill out required information?
- If an envelope is created using anchor tags and recipient signs the document on paper, if the tags are not in correct place, what does DocuSign do? It still identifies those tags?
- Does DocuSign account have to have a special feature turned on to accept signed document via fax?

Please advise,

Thanks,

Minal

Comment: Hmm according to this [How-To](https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/question/how-do-i-send-a-docusign-document-by-fax-fax-out-feature) article faxing is only supported on certain DocuSign plans.  Can you confirm which plan you are using?

Comment: Anyone know if DocuSign faxing is supported in their demo environment? It will print the cover page, but when I fax the document back I'm not seeing the envelope updated either.